# wpf DataGrid Loses its Row Selection when the focus is lost

Tags: wpf

I have come accross a very strange behavior with the DataGrid. I have following Trigger on the DataGridRow

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectionBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Initially when the row is selected, I get the behavior from the above trigger. However, after selection, if the DataGrid loses focus (say for example I click some other button on window) the Foreground property loses its value, but the background remains as specified in the trigger. Has anyone ever come accross this behavior, or there is some problem with my code above (or elsewhere in my applicaion for that matter). Any workarounds for the above issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used DataGridCell instead of DataGridRow and it works for me

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#CCDAFF" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3399ff"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Hope it helps someone!